# Configuration to get class picked from classes folder instead of lib folder in Tomcat?

Tags: java, web-applications, webserver, tomcat6

I have same class file under classes folder and also in jar file inside lib folder.But the class is getting picked up from jar file. As per my understanding when this is the case , class under classes folder gets preference over jar file. At least this is the behaviour i have seen in glassfish. But this is not the behaviour in tomcat. Do i need to do any configuration in case of tomcat to give the preference to classes under classes folder? I am using  tomcat 6.0.26.

Comment: Why do you see it necessary to have a .class file in two places?  I think it's asking for trouble.  You'd remove all confusion if you'd have it in one place.

Comment: Actually its open source project.I just want to put my modified class under classes folder

Comment: Sorry, you modified an open source file yet you still put the JAR in your CLASSPATH?  Is that correct?

Comment: Jar contains lot of other classes too.

Comment: Yes, I get it.  Sounds like a situation that's asking for trouble.  What effect will your modifications have?  Are you sure they were necessary?  How will those other classes react to your new code.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The spec (2.4) says:

> The Web application class loader must load classes from the
>   WEB-INF/classes directory first, and then from library JARs in the
>   WEB-INF/lib directory.

So if Tomcat loads from the jar first, it's not compliant with the spec.

[Its documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html) says:

> Therefore, from the perspective of a web application, class or
>   resource loading looks in the following repositories, in this order:
>
> - Bootstrap classes of your JVM
> - System class loader classes (described above)
> - /WEB-INF/classes of your web application
> - /WEB-INF/lib/*.jar of your web application
> - Common class loader classes (described above)

So I'm surprised you're seeing such a behavior. If you're absolutely sure that the class is not in some jar in Tomcat's own classpath, file a bug report. Before doing that, also make sure to clear Tomcat's work directory, or even to start from a fresh install of Tomcat.

The workaround is of course to repackage the jar file to include your modified class instead of relying on the classloading order.

Comment: As you said If you're absolutely sure that the class is not in some jar in Tomcat's own classpath. where should i check if class is not in some jar in Tomcat's own classpath. Sorry for asking this?

Comment: Knowing the class would help. Also, see what `TheClass.class.getClassLoader()` returns. Also look at the result of `TheClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation()`.

Comment: @JBNizet how can we implement same for standalone application ?

Comment: @Vipin Implement what? The question is about the order in which locations are used to load classes in a webapp. I don't see how I could translate the question for a standalone app. If you have a specific question, then ask it as a question.